# Datatable adding a new row with row.add.draw() but with different content then the other rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to add a new row to the datatable loaded by ajax, but need the content of the new row to be different then the previous rows. I am using row.add.draw() and a new row is added to the table but with the same fields as the other rows. I need the new row to have a "ADD" button instead of "EDIT" and "DEL".

Here is the columns of the table in general:

```
columns: [
            { data: 'mls' },
            { data: 'steet' },        
            { data: 'city' },
            { data: 'zip' },
            { data: 'country' },             
            {'data': null, 'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<button id="del-'+row.mls+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs edit_active" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#del" >Delete</button>';
                 }

            },
```

this is the function of row.add.draw() :

```
$("#cur_act_tbl").DataTable().row.add({"mls": '',"street": '',"city": '',"zip": '',"country": ''}).draw();
```

[image: new row with different button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data add a `type` property that will tell DataTables if this is a new row or an existing one. You will need to modify your Ajax return to include this property also (but with the value "existing")

```js
{"mls": '',"street": '',"city": '',"zip": '',"country": '', "type": "new"}
```

Then in DataTables you just need to check for this property and return the corresponding button.

```js
columns: [
    { data: 'mls' },
    { data: 'steet' },        
    { data: 'city' },
    { data: 'zip' },
    { data: 'country' },             
    { render: (data, type, row, meta) =>  {
        let btn = '';
        if(row.type == 'new') {
            btn = '<button id="add-'+row.mls+'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit_active" data-title="Add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add">Add</button>';
        } else {
            btn = '<button id="edit-'+row.mls+'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_active" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">Edit</button>';
        }
        return btn;
    }

],
```